# Dual boot linux mint 17 with Windows 8

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I have ubuntu dual booted with Win 8. I had the ubuntu installed before dual booting it with windows 8.

Now I want to uninstall ubuntu and install Linux mint 17 instead. I burnt the iso image to USB, and chose boot from USB, but it shows me a message saying there is no bootable OS on the USB.

I tried to disable the secure boot, but when I opened the boot options I didn't find such option to disable it.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong and how to dual boot Linux mint 17 with Windows 8??

**EDIT**

here is a picture of the boot options I got.
[image]

Comment: Can you boot other live distros from a USB? If yes, then your main problem at this stage seems to be that your Linux Mint 17 .iso isn't recognized as a bootable media. How did you burn the iso to the USB? If you haven't tried dd the iso, do that first and report back. Just make sure you identify the right /dev/sdX to write to, so use fdisk -l before that and find your USB so you don't write the iso to another partition.

Comment: Do you have EFI boot enabled in your BIOS? Mint 17 may not support EFI booting. Check here "http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/"

Comment: @Joe I didn't find any option related to EFI in the BIOS.

Comment: @fantasia no I can't boot from any other live distros from a USB. I burned the iso using isotousb application on Windows.

Comment: What boot options do you have in the BIOS? Could you outline them, or post a picture? Almost all computers enable access to both a main UEFI Settings/Startup Menu and a separate Boot Menu.

I suspect that Win 8 was installed in UEFI/EFI-mode, which means you will want to boot Linux Mint in UEFI/EFI-mode. If it gets booted in Legacy mode, you will end up with an installation that won't boot, or the installer will not recognize that Windows exists on the hard drive.

Which version of Linux Mint 17 do you have? 32- or 64-bit? If my memory serves me only the 64-bit allows booting in UEFI/EFI-mode.

Comment: @fantasia I updated the question check it please . I have 64 bit version of linux mint 17

Comment: Thanks for the update and it's good you have the 64-bit version. I see CD-ROM boot is enabled, could you boot Linux Mint 17 from that instead of a USB? I am asking since I want to see if the .iso-burning method is working or not. If you can't boot any live distro using the CD either, then I suspect the burning method is the problem. If so, try using UNetbootin or PendriveLinux instead. I do not see a USB boot alternative on your screen shot, neither do I see your Boot Order, but you say you have enabled USB-boot - right?

Comment: @fantasia I burned it to a cd and it worked, Can you please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use win32 Disk Imager utility to burn the iso which i am sure will work for you but if it doesn't work, you could use rufus and try to use different partition schemes till you get the right one since you can't determine

Comment: @Alaa Did you try my suggestion?